# The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression

Tags: haskell, syntax

Like it says in the title: What does The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression mean? I know there are other subjects similar to mine, but I still can't find my error.

Code:

```
import System.Environment

check_args argc args i = do
        putStrLn $ show (args !! i)
        i <- return (i + 1)
        if argc > i
                then mydisplay2 argc args i
                else return i

loop_args argc args = do
        let i = 0
        i <- check_args argc args i

main = do
        args <- getArgs
        putStrLn "The arguments are:"
        loop_args (length args) args
```

Comment: The `i <- check_args argc args i` makes no sense, since you do not do anything with the `i`. You can rewrite it to just `check_args argc args i`. But it looks to me that you aim to program something in Haskell in an *imperative* way. Note that normally one does not use that much `do`, `return` is *not* a keyword, but a function, and works differently than what you expect in an imperative language.

Comment: All right, thanks for your answer. I'm new to Haskell, I'm completely lost, what I'm trying to do is check argv one by one  and then compare them.

Comment: I highly recommend [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) as the best and most readable/understandable introduction to the language. [This chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) will be most relevant to your immediate needs, but I highly recommend reading the earlier chapters too, especially to get a feel to how pure functional programming is different from imperative programming.

Comment: If you were to attempt to desugar that `do` block, you would wind up with `check_args args args i >>= \i -> `: a lambda expression with no body.

Comment: @chepner another way to show it is to say that by the Monad laws any do block `do { .... ; A }` is equivalent to `do { .... ; r <- A ; return r }` and `r <- i <- ....` is meaningless wrong syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is located in the `loop_args` function:

```
loop_args argc args = do
        let i = 0
        i <- check_args argc args i
```

It makes no sense to write `i <- …`, since you here define a *new* variable named `i` (that has not much to do with the `i` in `let i = 0`), and you do not use that variable at all. You can replace it with `check_args argc args i` and the error will go away, but likely it will still not work the way you want this to work.

But in general, the program looks *imperative*, whereas Haskell is a *declarative* language. It means that every variable (so `i`) is immutable, you thus can *not* loop by *incrementing* a variable. Furthermore in a declarative language, there is not much "looping", etc. The aim is not to specify *how* you want to do something, but *what* you want to do.

You likely here want to use a [**`mapM_ :: (Foldable f, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> f a -> m ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_) that can move through a `Foldable` object, and apply the monadic function on all items:

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    putStrLn "The arguments are:"
    mapM_ putStrLn args
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How to use this mapM to check if one of my arguments is equal to "foo" for example

Comment: @Sanka: you can use [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) to filter a list of items, or [`any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any) to check if any item in the list satisfies a given predicate. But I think it might help to first try some simple expressions (and not work in `do` contexts for now). Monads are a very expressive concept, but it requires, unfortunately some experience to get used to it.

Comment: "Modern" Haskell is `traverse_` not `mapM_` (though you will need to import it `import Data.Foldable (traverse_)`).

Comment: Haskell is not declarative, and it got loops aplenty. there's even a package for monad loops, called `monad-loops`. of course coding up a loop by manual indexing and yes incrementing is a redundant kludge. `mapM_` is also a kludge; mapping implies list transformation into something new but here it is done purely for side effect. the name to express that intent is [`for_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:for_).

Comment: @WillNess: the `for_` loop is constructed with `flip traverse_`. Furthermore having loops does not make something non-declarative. For example the `for` looping mechanism in Kotlin is definitely more declarative than the one in Java, since updating the iterator in the loop, has no effect in the next iteration. Haskell is of course not a declarative language in the sense that there is still "control" (it is not just data). But I think most people will agree that it is more declarative than Java for example :).